# Where can I look up FAA Letters to Airmen?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control

I was recently asked if an airport was covered by a Letter to Airmen (LTA) providing IFR separation for VFR practice approaches, and I realized I had no idea. How can I look up LTAs for an airport, and do they ever expire?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are searchable at FNS NOTAM search: https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/

A link is provided to a PDF, containing a link to the actual LTA.

(Filter by LTA, remember the agreement might not be with the airport, but with the ATSU, like the local TRACON/ARTCC, try searching by airport name + radius).

Expiry date is shown in the details view.

Comment: Importantly, to actually read the letter, you need to click on the camouflaged "PDF" link at the top, then follow the link in the download to the main LTA document. Not the best flow.

Comment: Not the best flow indeed :) I'll add it to the answer for completeness if you don't mind.

Comment: Of course, go for it!